# Why is UUID column VARCHAR(128)?

Tags: 8, database, entities

Just wondering if anyone knows why `uuid` columns created by Drupal 8 in MySQL are of type `VARCHAR(128)`, not `CHAR(36)`?

Comment: Good question. Related issue on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/1805576.

Answer (score 3):

Basing on [this comment by Damien Tournoud](https://www.drupal.org/node/1805576#comment-6572344), the idea was to support arbitrary string identifiers.
Since [Drupal uses a service to generate UUIDs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/uuid/8.2.x), using a `VARCHAR(128)` as database field for the UUID would allow a module to override the current service with one using a different implementation, and using more bytes for the UUID.